# Dynamic Width Adjustment of a Column in Tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Hi everyone,
             I wanted to adjust the width of a tablix column dynamically. can some one please let me know how can this be done? when i searched some forums there was a suggestion that i try creating an instance of the report in the CODE of the report properties and access the tablix column using the instance but i wasn't able to do that. Can some one please help if indeed i can try creating an instance of the report and access the tablix and adjust the width dynamically ?

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically, do you want to be able to manually drag the column border as in excel after rendering, or do you want the column with to automatically change based on size of dataset or do you want the column with to be set by the user before the report renders. The first solution mentioned is not possible the other two are possible

Comment: thanks for replying. So i have a tablix with 4 columns occupying the length of the report. Now on a particular condition the 3rd column will be hidden. so now i have 3 columns. the 4th column will be next to the 2nd column. Now because of this i have extra space on the right and hence to remove this extra space i want the first column's width to increase so that my tablix with 3 columns will still occupy the entire length of the page with the first column widening in the report.

Comment: One thing you can do is keep only one column for 2 and 3 with one placeholder each and control the content of the placeholders via expression

Answer (score 1):

There is no property to auto size the column width. Length we can do it dynamically. That is the limitation Microsoft tools.

For now, one solution is to have a reasonable fixed column width (such, as 30) and set the textbox CanGrow to True so it wraps to next line if needed. Another solution is to have two columns and hide one of them conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

On the off-chance that anybody is still looking for a way to have dynamic column widths in SSRS (as I was), I've found way that works for most scenarios.

Basically you add another column header to your table/matrix/tablix and set your column to your minimum required width, then add a subreport to the new header. The subreport consists of a matrix with a static row group and a dynamic column group that generates a number of fixed-size columns based on the desired width, which is passed via a parameter from the main report to the subreport.

e.g. Your main report has a column where you want to set the width from data or a parameter, which is in a range from 5 to 10cm, with increments of 1cm. Let's say for a particular column you pass down 7cm to the subreport, which then does a basic SQL loop to produce some data with 7 rows. The matrix column grouping in the subreport points to that data, which produces 7 columns, each 1cm, for a total width of 7cm (plus the row grouping which is shrunk as much as possible). The main report's column then expands to the size of the subreport, which is 7cm.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Select the first column, in properties, find the width property (under size) add an expression that uses the same condition for hiding column 3 and increasing the width of the first column, e.g.</strike>

```
=iif(parameters!par.value=true,"1,5cm","2,5cm")
```

--EDITED --

I'm very sorry my previous solution was false, I hadn't checked it, I'm sorry to have wasted your time, but I have a solution that works.
create two first columns, i.e. two columns that show the same information, one that is the width that you like when column 3 is visible (lets call that one col1a) and one that is the width that is suitable to when column 3 is hidden (col1b) and then make those two alternate. then when you hide column 3 then you also hide col1a and make col1b visible and then the other way around

Comment: In 2008 R2 I've tried using an expression for width, on a text box and on a column, and both reject it with an error message. Do other versions of SSRS allow it?

Comment: I created a report with a parameter called 'par', so I could paste in your exact expression. `Property value is not valid. =iif(parameters!par.value=true,"1,5cm","2,5cm") cannot be parsed as a unit because it does not contain numeric values. Examples of valid unit strings are "1pt" and ".5in".` Most properties that allow expressions have an <Expression> option you can choose, but in 2008 R2 Width and Height don't.

Comment: changed my answer, sorry for the false answer at first

Answer (score 0):

You can use a chart :
"graphique en barre empilée" or "stacked bar chart"

I tried it and it works very well.